# why inserting folder in google drive twice

Tags: vb.net, insert, google-drive-api, subdirectory

In my application with vb.net , i managed to create folder and subfolder , file , but my problem is when i create subfolder ,file (in folder parent) , i found my subfolder in drive and in folder parent (i found it twice and i want it only in folder parent )

here is my code

```
Public Function subfolder_creation(id_sub As String) As String
    Dim subfolder As New Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File()
    subfolder.Title = VF.Text

    subfolder.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    Dim ref = Service.Files.Insert(subfolder)
    MessageBox.Show("sous dossier crée")
    ref.Fields = "id"
    Dim a = ref.Execute()
    MessageBox.Show(" Id Subfolder  " & a.Id)
    Dim reference = New ParentReference()
    reference.Id = id_sub
    Dim insert = Service.Parents.Insert(reference, a.Id).Execute
    MessageBox.Show("Création sous dossier avec succés")
    Dim reference_file = New ParentReference()
    reference_file.Id = a.Id
    UploadFile(reference_file.Id)
    Return (a.Id)
```

i know the problem is from two insert instruction , but i don't know how i solve it

Answer (score 0):

I cant test vb but you should be able to do it all in one request

```
Dim subfolder As New Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File()
subfolder.Title = VF.Text
subfolder.Parents = parentFolderId
subfolder.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
```

Add the parent to the body of the insert of the sub folder.  In theory you should be able to [patch](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/patch) the sub folder with the parent after the insert but its kind of over kill IMO.  Just do it when you insert it.

Comment: Can i get folder(sub folder ) id without using 
Dim ref = Service.Files.Insert(subfolder) ???

Comment: No you need to insert it before it has an id. Then when you upload a file to it you can just set the parent of the file to that of the sub folder

Comment: you mean , i remove 
 Dim insert = Service.Parents.Insert(reference, a.Id).Execute ?

Comment: I don't actually understand why you are doing that. Create sub folder returns the folder ID create a file set the parent ID to the sub folder id.   Will add to file under the sub folder.

Comment: i create function creat folder , function create sub folder , and another for creating file which return id 
and i don't know how i use id folder (in folder function) in sub folder method

Comment: when I used this 
subfolder.Parents = parentFolderId

error is :
 
System.InvalidCastException : 'Impossible d'effectuer un cast d'un objet de type 'Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.ParentReference' en type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1