# Exception in Creation subfolder vb.net

Tags: vb.net, exception, directory

I develop an application , and i have a problem , after reading [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45460135/why-inserting-folder-in-google-drive-twice/45463961?noredirect=1#comment77897226_45463961) , i try to use this instruction

```
Public Function subfolder_creation(id_sub As String) As String
         Dim subfolder As New Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File()
        subfolder.Title = VF.Text
    Dim reference As ParentReference ' référencier au dossier parent
    reference.Id = id_sub
    subfolder.Parents.Add(reference)
    subfolder.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
 Dim reference As ParentReference ' référencier au dossier parent
    reference.Id = id_sub

    subfolder.Parents.Add(reference)
```

Exception is in instruction : subfolder.parent.add(reference)

System.NullReferenceException : 'La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet.'

translate to english : System.NullReferenceException: 'The object reference is not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: but when i get break point and inspect my variable value , all are correct
subfolder title is correct
reference = id_sub is correct
id_sub has a same value from another method

Comment: no i change it to 
Dim reference = new ParentReference() ....and the same exception

Comment: Well something is null. Either it is something in `reference`, `subfolder`, `subfolder.Parents` or something internal.

Comment: reference has a same value with id_sub (also same value from another method) , sudfolder has a correct title , subfolder.parents is nothing 
but i think is no problem because after .add instruction , subfolder.parents will take a value... but first it's nothing

Comment: I think you're setting `subfolder.MimeType` too late. Move it up above the `subfolder.Parents.Add()` call.

Comment: i move it , but the same result

Comment: My final suggestion (I've never used the Drive API so my suggestions are just based on research): Reading the [**documentation**](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/folder) they seem to create the list themselves, so what if you try `subfolder.Parents = New List(Of String)` before the first `subfolder.Parents.Add()`?

Comment: System.InvalidCastException : 'Impossible d'effectuer un cast d'un objet de type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' en type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.ParentReference]'.'

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I was reading another version of the documentation. I meant: `New List(Of ParentReference)`.

Comment: yes , i used parentreference 
I think it's work , thank you very much

Comment: So the list was null after all ;). Glad I could help! Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears it is the `Parents` list that is null. Try initializing it before the first `Add()` call:

```
subfolder.Parents = New List(Of ParentReference)
subfolder.Parents.Add(reference)
```